# Hpricot search all the tags under one specific namespace

Tags: parsing, xhtml, jruby, xml-namespaces, hpricot

For example I have the following code:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title><io:content part="title" /></title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/document/7e9f29e2-cdee-4f85-ba25-132fa867aa90/latest" type="image/x-icon" />
  <n1:content description="Standard CSS" uuid="d069071c-3534-4945-9fb6-2d7be35a165e" />
  <n1:term>Content Development</n1:term>
</head>
```

This XHTML snippet is not strictly legal because there is no namespace declared before so I cannot use Nokogiri which has better namespace support.

I want to do a single search that can find both the node `<n1:content>` and `<n1:term>` and all the tags under 'n1' namespace.

How to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Hpricot does not handle namespaces that fully.

You can select if you know the element regardless of prefix:

```
doc.search("title")
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{elem <title> {emptyelem <io:content part="title">} </title>}]>
```

... but this is not what you asked.

Here's my hack workaround: find all namespace elements using regex first, then search for those using Hpricot:

```
elems = doc.to_s.scan(/<\s*(n1:\w+)/).uniq.join("|")
=> "n1:content|n1:term"
doc.search(elems)
=> #<Hpricot::Elements[{emptyelem <n1:content description="Standard CSS" uuid="d069071c-3534-4945-9fb6-2d7be35a165e">}, {elem <n1:term> "Content Development" </n1:term>}]>
```

Comment: thank you. I did the workaround by this:traverse_element(*@io_tags)